# Showing Image to my page from database

Tags: php, image, echo

I created a page to show the table in my database. But the problem is the image is not showing properly instead it is giving the link of my image for example:(../../images/i1.jpg) Is something wrong with my code?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include('connect-db.php');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products9 ORDER BY id ASC")
or die(mysql_error());
echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Product</th> <th>Price</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['p_name'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['image'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>
</body>
</html>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<img src="<?=$row['image']?>" >`

Comment: Tried it and It is not working: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\shop\pages\view.php on line 18" Sorry I'm new to PHP and Programming

Comment: I think your string concatenation is wrong try this on line 18 `echo '<td>' . "<img src=\"".$row['image'] ."\"></td>";`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't use img tag and just you put image URL to td tag
solution :
change this line :

```
echo '<td>' . $row['image'] . '</td>';
```

to this :

```
echo '<td><img src="' . $row['image'] . '" /></td>';
```

if there was problem again , check Image URL in browser to see that images appears or not !